Dot operator not clickable and lightbulb icon appearing in IntelliJ
I'm currently working on a Java Spring project and trying to add elements to a List<String> using the .add() method. However, when I type the dot (.) after declaring my list the (.) is not functioning i.e. after clicking the '.' it is not shown in the editor, IntelliJ doesn't recognize the dot operator. a lightbulb icon appears next to the line, and the tooltip suggests "Not a statement."
@Bean
public Subjects Msub() {
    Subjects subj = new Subjects();
    List<String> subjList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // Issue occurs here when I try to use the .add() method
    subjList.add("Math");  // The dot operator is not clickable, and IntelliJ shows a lightbulb.
    
    return subj;
}`

I ensured that my list was initialized properly and checked for syntax errors, but the issue persists.
Troubleshooting Attempts:

Checked imports: I verified that java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList are imported correctly.
Rebuilt the project: I tried rebuilding the project to ensure all dependencies were loaded.
Invalidated caches and restarted IntelliJ: This didn’t resolve the issue.
Used IntelliJ suggestions (Alt/Option + Enter): IntelliJ offers no helpful suggestions, just stating "Not a statement."



but when I directly copy and paste the code, it works


Image

Show us all the code.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the problem? Why had you want the dot to be cliackable? IntelliJ IDEA is right, subjList alone is not at statement. When you type the entire line, do you get any error message? If so, please paste it into your question.

When I try the same, my IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate does suggest relevant methods after I type the dot (provided that I have already imported the relevant types including List and ArrayList). Is this behaviour described in any source? If not, I would not consider it a bug when it doesn‘t on your computer. After all we‘re supposed to be able to write the code and not depend on IDEA writing it for us.

how can I write even manually if the dot "." button is not clickable?
then how can i call the add() method for that i have to use "." then add() if i the dot is not clickable then how i proceed further.

You talk about the "dot button is not clickable". It's neither a button, nor does clicking it do anything. If you want code suggestions, you usually type the dot and wait – or press Ctrl+Space to trigger the autocompletion feature (check your keymap settings). I'm not sure why you want to click the dot? That said, your method won't compile: You cannot return a List<String> from a method that's declared to return an object of type Subjects.

Why do you think you need IntelliJ to add the add() method for you? Why can't you just type "add" yourself after the dot?

Are you saying that nothing happens when you type the dot (period) and the word add from your keyboard? Sorry, I still don‘t think I understand the question.

If you're facing an issue where the dot (.) operator is not functioning in IntelliJ, the solution is simple. Try either reinstalling IntelliJ or resetting your keymap to default settings. This should resolve the problem effectively.

To eliminate the possibility that the problem is in the IDE itself, try to reinstall it. I had a similar problem with JetBrains Rider once, which was solved by reinstalling it.
